# Dictionary.GetKey Returns False Even Though Key Is Present - GetHashCode/Equals Already Overridden

Tags: c#, dictionary, keynotfoundexception

This is in C#. I have a problem whereby Dictionary.ContainsKey returns false even though I know the key to be in there.

I don't have any code to show unfortunately. The code is not easy to pull together; it is spread across multiple classes and triggered through events and so on. A quick unit test I wrote didn't reproduce the problem.

Here is the output of the immediate window during a debugging session (added comments and changed to protect details):

```
// throws KeyNotFoundException
myDict[key]  

// throws KeyNotFoundException
myDict[new MyKey("SomeString .1", "SomeOtherString", SomeEnum.Foo)]

// Element [5] is the key
myDict.Keys
Count = 10
    [0]: {...}
    [1]: {...}
    [2]: {...}
    [3]: {...}
    [4]: {...}
    [5]: {Foo SomeOtherString SomeString  .1}
    [6]: {...}
    [7]: {...}
    [8]: {...}
    [9]: {...}

// Get key at element [5]   
enumerator.Current
{Foo SomeOtherString SomeString  .1}
    [My.Namespace.KeyType]: {Foo SomeOtherString SomeString  .1}
    SomeEnum: Foo
    SomeOtherStringProperty: "SomeOtherString"

// key used to do lookup
key
{Foo SomeOtherString SomeString  .1}
    [My.Namespace.KeyType]: {Foo SomeOtherString SomeString  .1}
    SomeEnum: Foo
    SomeOtherStringProperty: "SomeOtherString"

// hash codes of key in dictionary matches hash code of lookup key
enumerator.Current.GetHashCode()
193014103
key.GetHashCode()
193014103
```

Some extra notes:

- The type used as the key has overridden methods for GetHashCode and
  Equals.
- The dictionary is constructed as new Dictionary() with
  no extra constructor arguments.
- By debugging, I've verified that
  GetHashCode in the key type is called, but not Equals(obj)
- When the
  application runs, there's only one DLL loaded that has the key type,
  so it's probably not a case of the same type in different versions of
  the same DLL

Does anyone know why this might be occuring?

Thanks for any help - I'm running out of ideas here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The type used as the key has overridden methods for GetHashCode and Equals.

This is the first thing that I would check. If the hash code is based on a mutable value, it could definitely cause this problem.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> In general, for mutable reference types, you should override GetHashCode only if:
>
> - You can compute the hash code from fields that are not mutable; or
> - You can ensure that the hash code of a mutable object does not change while the object is contained in a collection that relies on its hash code.
>
> Otherwise, you might think that the mutable object is lost in the hash table. If you do choose to override GetHashCode for a mutable reference type, your documentation should make it clear that users of your type should not modify object values while the object is stored in a hash table.

Comment: Indeed. If you mutate properties that participate in GetHashCode/Equality comparisons while the object in question is stored in a Dictionary (or any HashTable-like structure), you'll corrupt the Dictionary and all bets are off. All properties that participate in GetHashCode and Equality really should be immutable. Don't rely on documentation for this.

Comment: Thanks. However, given that all the output of the immediate window above was taken while the app was held on a breakpoint and the hash codes were the same, it seems unlikely this was the problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ck: That the Dictionary corruption had occurred prior to the breakpoint, i.e. you mutated the key after it went into the dictionary causing it to generate a different code to the one that was used by the Dictionary to store it. Yes, you can enumerate the keys, but because they were stored against a different hash code, you can't find it.

Comment: @spender: Good point. To test this, I got to the same breakpoint, then created in the immediate window an instance of MyKey using the same property values I expected the key in the dictionary to have. Both the immediate window's newly created key, and the key in the dictionary have the same hash code.

Comment: @ck: Sure, but did the key in the dictionary have the same hash code **at the moment when it was stored in the dictionary**? If not, your key lookup will fail because the item is in the wrong hashtable bucket.

Comment: Checked out the code and I think you're right - thanks for the help!